# How to run chrome webdriver in google colab?

Tags: selenium

**How to run chrome webdriver in google colab?**

**pip install**

1. !pip install selenium
2. !apt-get update
3. !apt install chromium-chromedriver
4. !cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin

`my sample code`

```
from selenium import webdriver 

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)
url = "https://www.instagram.com/" 

driver.get(url)
```

**my picture**

[image]

When I run the chrome webdriver in colab,

`I want to see the execution process with a window.`

But the window won't open.

> How do I deal with this?

**update post**
[image]

**update post2**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To see the browser opened etc. you should run the browser in regular mode while currently you are running in headless more.
So, you just have not to use `options.add_argument('--headless')`

Comment: `Except options.add_argument('--headless') an error occurs.`

What should I do?

Comment: Posting updated successfully.
I'd really appreciate it if you could see the error.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would remove all the other `options` and trying run driver with default profile setting

Comment: @ProphetI tried except for the option, but there was still an error.

Posting updated successfully.

Comment: Hm... to say the truth: I didn't use selenium with Python for several years, so I don't know. I even have no Python on my computer these days...

Comment: Oh my God...

I have one question for you.
`Google CORAP Linux? OR Windows?`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question